# How to use React Components without CDN and minified js on clients?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm

I am building an app with MERN(MongoDB, Express, React Nodejs) stacks and [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). On my client side, I use CDNs to load React and React-DOM, and I place a minified axios file in Express's public javascripts directory.

I want to use this [datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) but it does not have a CDN or a minified file. I installed the datepicker by:

```
npm install react-datepicker --save
```

but it loads it to my server right? How can I use it on my client side? I am confused.

Comment: Here is the cdn of `react-datepicker` https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-datepicker

Comment: @Prakashsharma THANK YOU! So, I am supposed to find CDNs or make them by myself?

Comment: If you know the name of the `npm` package, which is `react-datepicker` in this case, you can use `unpkg.com`. You go to [https://unpkg.com/react-datepicker](https://unpkg.com/react-datepicker) and copy the generated url as a CDN url.

Comment: @norbertpy OH, nice! So, is everybody making own CDNs or minified js files to use node modules on clients?

Comment: from the website: 
> unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm.